# Meta tags not showing on front page

Tags: 7, nodes, meta-tags

I'm using the module "metatag" to make my website SEO friendly. This works very well for all pages except the front page.

I go to modules -> Meta tags -> Settings -> Global: Front page

There I set a description. But this description isn't shown if you search the site directly in google. All other pages are working great, with the correct description.

When I look at the source, I see no meta data included at the front page.

Comment: How do you assign a mode to be 'front'? I created the "page--front.tpl.php". The homepage works as expected. Its just the Meta data doesnt appear?

Comment: you should have a look at this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1284852#comment-6561682) of meta-tags. It's the same problem and seems to be fixed in the latest dev version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a node to be 'front'. Otherwise the meta won't show.

Comment: ahaaaa... That will be the problem I guess. I'll take a closer look to your answer! Thanks in advance!