# Hotel Diamond and Metatag: the META information doesn't appear in front page

Tags: meta-tags

I have a site using Drupal 7 and the Hotel Diamond theme. I am trying to add META tags to all the pages in my site (description, Open Graph tags, etc.), and it's working in all of them except the front page. What I do is:

- I have Metatag 7.x-1.13
- In the admin page, I go to "Modules/SEO", and I make sure that Metatag, Metatag:OpenGraph, Metatag:Facebook, Metatag:Twitter Cards and Metatag:Views are activated.
- I go to "Content" and, in each of the pages, I hit "Edit" and add the descriptions in "Meta tags".
- I go to "Configuration/Search and metadata/Metatag" and, in "Global: Front page", I add my description for the front page.

When I check my pages, all of them have the proper META tags... except the front page.

I've seen [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36068/meta-tags-not-showing-on-front-page), but I don't really understand the answer: how do you assign a node to be front? Besides, in the case of Hotel Diamond, there seems to be a front page already assigned that you modify by editing it directly when logged in.

Answer (score 1):

To change/set the front page go to admin/settings/site-information, where you can set the path for the node that you want to be your front page.

Comment: What I have there is just: http://example.com/?q=node. So how do I access that "node"?